# ohai's executable "ohai" conflicts with /usr/bin/ohai

Tags: chef-infra

I am installing chef github gem. It is trying to replace ohai. Should i say yes or No ? I have installed chef cdk from chef website on my mac

`gem install knife-github-cookbooks`

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.9.10
Fetching: ohai-8.5.1.gem (100%)
ohai's executable "ohai" conflicts with /usr/bin/ohai
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

Comment: Which package do you want to provide your active ohai binary? There isn't really an official right answer to this. If they're both the same release, either should be suitable. If they're not the same release, I'd suggest going with whichever is newer.

Comment: As there isn't a fact-based Right Answer to this, I'm not sure it's a question well-suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: You should be able to update ohai in chef dk, there's no breaking change in minor version bump usually. If it turns wrong, just downgrade the ohai gem. Chef dk bundle a lot of gems in it's install, some are not always the last version or a new release is done after chef-dk release. Usually Chef Inc will make a new release of chef-dk when an ohai or chef release goes to breaking change.